# MultiSelect in django no alloiwng multiple choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have an option for the user to select times, (half hours of the day), they can select as many as they like, and there are no constraints so (00:00, 01:00, 01:30) would be ok. But I can't get that to work as a field, I always get (is not in the available choices, as the specific combination will not be in their unless I enumerate all, but even with that I've struggled. Current files:

forms.py

```
from django import forms 
from .models import InputData

class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InputData
        fields = ('periods')
        widgets = {
                'periods': forms.MultipleSelect(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': 48}),
```

models.py

```
times_list = ['00:00', '00:30','01:00','01:30','02:00']

periods_choices = list(choices(times_list,times_list))

class InputData(models.Model):
    periods = models.CharField("Available periods:",
                                        max_length=96,
                                        choices=periods_choices,
                                        blank=False,
                                        default='all')
```

I've tried enumerating all the possibilities with `itertools.combinations` but I can't get the output to work as a set off choices.

Comment: In my opinion, you should to avoid to use multivaluated fields. To store multiple values you can use a related model with a foreign key to InputData. For example, [CommaSeparatedIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) is deprecated in favor of CharField with validator. How do you expect to store multiple strings in one string? Like a kind of csv row field?

Comment: @daniherrera this period data will get used in an SQL query to pick out info about the selected times in another table (availability off certain assets and prices) `select * where t in (list of periods from input)`, I was intending to store the selections as strings or list of strings, I haven't got that far yet.

Comment: My suggestion to you: Learn about importance of [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and avoid multivalueated fields.

Comment: @daniherrera thanks for the suggestion, I can see the importance in other applications, here though I'm not particularly interested in the users input and store it only for debugging purposes. The actual interest is on the sql query that this choice field informs.